# The GeoTIFF file appears only in white and black on Google Earth

Tags: qgis

When you import the GeoTIFF file from QGIS into Google Earth, it appears only in black and white.

[image]

So, I looked at [the answers here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiiPL.jpg) and I solved them by rendering.

However, if you look at the answer, it says that the image of one band is not recognized and that it can be an RGB image of three bands. Therefore, I merged the three bands R, G, and B from QGIS to create RGB images.

I saved it as GeoTIFF and put it in Google Earth, but the result is the same as the picture above. I checked the information of the image in QGIS, and found that three bands were displayed normally.

Is there any other way to solve this problem besides rendering when saving?

Comment: Try `export as displayed`.